# Changing class using javascript in other pages

Tags: javascript, html, class

I don't know how to change a div's class by using JS on an other page. To specify, it will be like the class on page-A should change depending the JS changes on page-B. 
(If you click on a box in page-B, the content on page-A should change.)

Comment: Define "page"...

Comment: The page DOM is not accessible on another page. Or you talk about embedded pages?

Comment: Hi @sdave, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider adding some code examples of your problem, and solutions you've already tried to your question. I'd also recommend having a quick search for existing answers to your question already posted here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only amend the DOM of the page which is currently loaded. If you want to change a different page based on an action in a previous one you'd need to persist the state of the user's interactions and then amend the other page when it loads. To do that you can use localStorage, sessionStorage, session, cookies, or AJAX to store information on the server.